# how to stop the current execution in play framework

Tags: playframework

I have a template which takes lot of time to calculate and render. If i press escape in the browser it should stop executing the controller method and rendering the template. But now controller method executing until it's complete. This should not happen. how can i control this.

Answer (score 3):

You should not have long running code as part of your controllers as this will block the http threads. Your controllers should be very quick. Pressing escape will close the http connection on the browser side but will not stop the controller from executing.

The best way to achieve this is to use a combination of caching and [asynchronous programming](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous).
I use jobs to perform heavy calculations, the controllers to get info from cache or call the jobs asynchronously if i have a cache miss. This works really well and very easy to implement.